# Search API: getAutocompleteSuggestions in D8?

Tags: 8, search

How can I use the function **getAutocompleteSuggestions()** in Drupal 8?
In Drupal 7 you could do something like this:

```
$query->getIndex()->server()->getAutocompleteSuggestions($query, $this->getSearch(), $incomplete_key, $user_input);
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe there is a solution with the Solarium client? http://solarium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/queries/suggester-query/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it with [Solarium](http://www.solarium-project.org/)

```
//...
use Solarium\Client;
//...

// $value is the search value from the textfield. 
if (!empty($value)) {
    $searchAPIconfig = \Drupal::config('search_api.server.server');
    $searchAPIconfigData = $searchAPIconfig->getRawData();

    $config = array(
    'endpoint' => array(
      'localhost' => array(
        'host' => $searchAPIconfigData['backend_config']['host'],
        'port' => $searchAPIconfigData['backend_config']['port'],
        'path' => $searchAPIconfigData['backend_config']['path'],
      ),
    ),
    );

    $client = new Client($config);

    if ($client !== NULL) {
        $query = $client->createSuggester();
        $query->setQuery($value);
        $query->setDictionary('mySuggester');
        $query->setOnlyMorePopular(TRUE);
        $query->setCount(10);
        $query->setCollate(TRUE);

        $resultset = $client->suggester($query)->getData();
        $results = $resultset['suggest']['mySuggester'][$value]['suggestions'];
        $suggestions = array();
        foreach ($results as $key => $termResult) {
          $suggestions[] = $termResult['term'];
        }

        //...
    }
}
```